# Oracle JDK 9 get AgentLoadException

Tags: java-9, jmockit

I am using Oracle Jdk 9.0.4 and Jmockit. However, when I add

```
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf
```

in my VM argument for my test file, I got the following errors.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.sun.tools.attach.AgentLoadException: Agent JAR not found or no Agent-Class attribute
Caused by: com.sun.tools.attach.AgentLoadException: Agent JAR not found or no Agent-Class attribute
```

My colleagues didn't get such kind of error. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this can be caused by many reasons. For my case, it was caused by the space in my windows user folder name. So I config my repo folder to another path (without any space in the path) and it worked.